# Implementar unity container

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Estoy armando la arquitectura y me falta definir la inyección de dependencias.
La idea es configurar `unity` en un proyecto de librería de clases para poder reutilizarla (¿es posible esto?)

Tengo la siguiente estructura:

> **Solucion.Core** (Defino las interfaces y modelos)
>
> **Solucion.Infrastructure** (EF e implementacion de repositorios)
>
> **Solucion.Infrastructure.Service** (Implementacion de servicios)
>
> --UI
>
> **Solucion.Mvc1**
>
> **Solucion.Mvc2**
>
> --WEB API
>
> **Solucion.Mvc1.WebApi**
>
> **Solucion.Mvc2.WebApi**

La idea es crear un nuevo proyecto para la inyección:

> **Solucion.Infrastructure.DependencyInyection**

e inyectar las dependencias en los proyectos `WebApi` que ya tengo definido.

¿Es correcta la arquitectura que estoy siguiendo?

¿Qué pasa si necesito utilizar el proyecto de inyección de dependencia en una o mas `class library` además de los proyectos `WebApi`? ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo genérico?

Saludos

Comment: La arquitectura la veo correcta, aunque no queda claro porque dos proyecto Mvc1 y 2 lo mismo porque dos WebApi ? proque no puedes unificarlo en uno, quizas en Mvc usando Areas   http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/714356/Areas-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Comment: Decidi agrupar toda la logica en el core y en infrastructure ya que Mvc1 es un proyecto web que no tiene relacion "directa" por asi decirlo con Mvc2. La solucion apunta al mismo objetivo. @LeandroTuttini es posible inyectar dependencia en los proyectos web api y tambien en una o mas class library con el mismo proyecto unity?

Comment: claro, si en el Application_Start de los proyecto web defines el mismo UnityContainer con los mismo mapping entre las interfaces y als clases concretas al resolver inyectara resolvera de la misma forma

Answer (score 1):

Aqui una excelente guia muy completa

[ASP.NET MVC 4 Dependency Injection](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection)

En realidad en el proyecto `DependencyInyection` no vas a realizar la inyeccion, lo que harias alli es definir el mapping entre las interfaces y las clases que deben inyectarse. Cuando el pipeline de mvc ejecute usara los datos de este proyecto para inyectar al constructor la instancia.

Por lo que comentas entiendo que en ese proyecto `DependencyInyection` definiras la clase que cargara el UnityContainer que usaras en el Application_Start para que mvc resuleva las dependencias.

Lo que si hay un tema, no se con cual librerias vas a trabajar pero si usas mvc 5 por ejemplo con [Unity.Mvc5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc5/)

[Using Unity.Mvc5 and Unity.WebApi together in a project](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/using-unity.mvc5-and-unity.webapi-together-in-a-project)

Notaras que la informa de registrar el `UnityDependencyResolver` cambia si es un proyecto mvc o si es webapi, por eso ese proyecto comun que defina las librerias que devuelva el una instancia del `UnityContainer` con todos los mapping definidos y nada mas, despues segun donde lo uses lo asignaras al `DependencyResolver`de esta forma ese proyecto que define los mapping te queda generico para usar en ambos tipos de proyectos mvc.

Comment: Leandro, Como hago para especificar que en el proyecto MVC1 tome el IUnityContainer que le corresponde ? Se lo debo pasar como parametro al UnityWebApiActivator.Start() ??

Comment: no entendi, que es eso del UnityWebApiActivator.Start() ? entiendo que no debes pasar nada de eso, en tu proyecto generico donde defines los mapping entre intefaces y clases concretas devuelves un objetos UnityContainer, despues donde asignas este dependera de cada tipo de proyecto ya sea mvc o webapi

Comment: Estoy usando la ultima version de unity web api, lo cual tiene dos clases, unityconfig.cs donde se definen los mappings y devuelve el objeto UnityContainer y la clase UnityWebApiActivator que es la que tiene el metodo Start() donde se define el resolver, el cual toma los mappings desde este metodo: UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer() .. como hago para especificar el de cada proyecto ?

Comment: la verdad no se cual sera esa version de unity web api que usas, pero si revisas el ultimo link que porpuse este asigna el UnityContainer en la linea  GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);  para webapi y  DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));  para mvc, no se de donde sale este UnityWebApiActivator

Comment: Claro si, y el container donde lo definiria para cada proyecto ? en cada proyecto mvc ?

Comment: pero la idea no era hacerlo global en el proyecto que llamarias Solucion.Infrastructure.DependencyInyection ? desde alli puedes definir el container. Despues referencias en cada proyecto mvc o webapi a este y lo asignas el  DependencyResolver